# Is there a way to know previous Steam sales?

Tags: steam

I would like to keep myself aware of Steam sale trends in order to know the games that are likely or not to be discounted in the future.

Is there a way to access Steam sales history globally **and** for a specific game?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not on Steam itself. However, third party websites such as [SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/sales/) exist specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 20):

I use a browser extension called [Enhanced Steam](https://www.enhancedsteam.com/) that gives me lowest price ever, lowest price currently, and if the game has (or is) in a bundle.
It searches a variety of websites, not just Steam, and I can also access a graph of price history, so I can see what is happening with any price fluctuations.

Comment: Enhanced Steam specifically uses https://isthereanydeal.com/ to source it's data from

Comment: As an avid trader, this is what I use myself.  +1

Answer (score 9):

If you're interested in a game on Steam and are interested in the price from anywhere you could try http://isthereanydeal.com.

Comment: I'm using it all the time, learnt it from Enhanced Steam. It can show you a graph of a game's price, which is helpful in identifying a pattern for sales.

Answer (score 7):

I've always used https://www.steamprices.com/

It also has a graph to show sale prices and the date of them